# LIRC irexec behaviour for top command without login

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-16.04, odroid, lirc

I have successfully configured LIRC on an Odroid XU4 with Cloudshell TFT display. IR keys are seen. I configured lircrc to send the top output to the TFT on a certain key. The TFT screen is actually waked and cleaned, but the *top* output is not displayed.

```
oc="/dev/tty1"
#wake display works fine
echo -ne "\033[9,2]" > $oc
# clear display works fine
echo -ne "\033c" > $oc

# execute top command 10 times and send output to TFT 
# this doesn't work with LIRC irexec
top -n 10 > $oc
```

I can send the above *top* command from via *ssh* - it works like a charm for the connected TFT (/dev/tty1). Does anyone know this issue? Thanks a lot in advance.
Btw., IR triggered shutdown and reboot works well.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the output of `stty -F /dev/tty1` and `stty -a` (for the ssh shell) I found the `echo` and `icanon` options on /dev/tty1 not enabled. Sending `stty -F /dev/tty1 echo icanon` and running the following line instead of the `top -n 10` works:

```
  ps -eo cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head -n 10 > /dev/tty1
```